# Why doesn't C++ find template function?

Tags: c++, function, templates

Why do I get the compile error `` no matching function for call to `f( __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >)' ``?

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void f(const typename std::vector<T>::iterator &) {}

void g() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  f<int>(v.end());  // Compiles.
  f(v.end());  // Doesn't compile, gcc 4.3 can't find any match.
}
```

Ultimately I want to write a function which takes only a vector iterator, and fails to compile (with a meaningful error) for anything else. So `template<typename T>void f(const T&) {}` is not a good solution, because it compiles for other types as well.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? The reason for the compile error is that you're not providing a type to the templated function call. Even though you've provided `int` as the vector type, you still need to specify it for the call to `f`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, template argument can not be deduced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G++ 4.8 gives a more complete message: http://ideone.com/ekN3xs

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
```

`f` doesn't directly takes a `T` (like in "`const T&`") or a type where `T` is clear (like in "`const std::vector<T>&`") but a nested dependent type (here `std::vector<T>::iterator`) so the template type `T` cannot be automatically deduced from the argument.

Edit: [Dietmar Kühl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301704/688659) gives a good rationale example.

---

For your "Ultimately" part, check [How to check whether a type is std::vector::iterator at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8101533/688659) (the accepted answer uses some C++11 types, but you can use C++03 equivalents, e.g. from Boost)

Comment: See also the video http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-2-of-n#time=37m30s (from about 37:30 to 42:00)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot deduce a template argument from a nested type. Think of, e.g., `std::vector<T>::size_type` which is always `std::size_t`: how would the compiler resolve the ambiguity? I realize that's not quite the case in your example but the same principle applies. For example, the iterator type of `std::vector<T>` can be `T*` which can also be the iterator type of `std::array<T, N>`.